# How to refactor multipler if statements into cleaner and easier to read code in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple if statements in a function like this :

```
    const handleCat = () => {
        if (mainCat === 'car') {
            return carCat;
        }
        if (mainCat === 'mobile') {
            return mobileCat;
        }
        if (mainCat === 'estate') {
            return estateCat;
        }
        if (mainCat === 'other') {
            return otherCat;
        }
    };
```

All the cat's are arrays with objects . I was wondering how can I refactor this code into much more cleaner and easier to read code ? How many ways are there to refactor multiple if statements in javascript ?

Comment: `Switch` statement makes more sense here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way which I would recommend will be to use an object type.

```
const genericCat = {
    car : carCat,
    mobile : mobileCat,
    estate:estateCat,
    other : otherCat
}

handleCat = (mainCat)=>{
return(generiCat[mainCat])
```

}

this approch also saves you from updating your code from more then one place if types of cat are increased.This is like using Enums in Java but with objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `switch` statement:

```
const handleCat = () => {
  switch (mainCat) {
    case 'car':
      return carCat;
    case 'mobile':
      return mobileCat;
    case 'estate':
      return estateCat;
    case 'other':
      return otherCat;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A switch statement is an option

```js
const handleCat = (mainCat) => {
  switch(mainCat) {
    case "car":
      return "carCat";
    case "mobile":
      return "mobileCat";
    case "estate":
      return "estateCat";
    case "other":
      return "otherCat";
    default:
      return "fallbackCat";
  }
};

const first = handleCat("car");
const second = handleCat();

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

You could also save the options in an object and return them based on their key.

```js
const handleCat = (mainCat) => {
  const fallback = "fallbackCat";
  
  const catMap = {
    car: "carCat",
    mobile: "mobileCat",
    estate: "estateCat",
    other: "otherCat",
  };
  
  return catMap[mainCat] || fallback;
};

const first = handleCat("car");
const second = handleCat();

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement:

```
var mainCat = 'car';

 const handleCat = () => {
    switch(mainCat) {
      case 'car':
        return carCat;
        break;
      case 'mobile:
        return mobileCat;
        break;
      case 'estate'
        return estateCat;
        break;
      default:
        return otherCat;
    }
}
```